# Overflow encountered when evaluating string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, overflow, eval

I got this error when I am trying to evaluate an expression f(x1, x2, ...) from a string based on given x1, x2, ...

```
I = eval(string)

<string>:1: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in long_scalars
```

The string represent a very long expression (~ MBs in txt file) and contains huge numbers (>int32), I am wondering how could I solve this? Is there any way to define the data type for the calculation involved in eval (I am guessing int64 probably work)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `int64` will work.

Please change your `int32` to `int64`.

The maximum value storable in an `int32` is `2**31-1`